# Spring Repository Custom Query Spel Evaluation Always Null

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Everytime I call the findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining function in my Repository I get the error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null
```

Is my query wrong? I am totally clueless with the error

Here are my files:

Person.java

```
package com.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    String firstName;

    String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
package com.repositories;

import com.model.Person;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName LIKE %:firstName% OR "
            + "p.firstName LIKE %:lastName% OR "
            + "p.lastName LIKE %:lastName% OR "
            + "p.lastName LIKE %:firstName%")
    public List<Person> findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(
        @Param(value = "firstName") String firstName, 
        @Param(value = "lastName") String lastName
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your %xxx% with just :{parameter} and it will work.

```
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import java.util.List;


public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

@Query("SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.firstName LIKE :firstName OR "
    + "e.firstName LIKE :lastName OR "
    + "e.lastName LIKE :lastName OR "
    + "e.lastName LIKE :firstName")
List<Employee> findByFirstNameContainingOrLastNameContaining(
    @Param(value = "firstName") String firstName,
    @Param(value = "lastName") String lastName
);
}
```